# UWP Xaml Intellisense from Nuget (Visual studio 2017)

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, nuget, uwp-xaml

I'm having a very difficult time getting XAML intellisense working with an assembly packaged in a Nuget.

I have created a nuget which contains a dll with a bunch of resource dictionaries. I have included all my .dll, .pdb, .pri, .xaml and .xr.xml files with the nuget.

In my consuming application, I am trying to make use of these resource dictionaries as follows:

```
<App.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///StyleTest/Brushes.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///StyleTest/Spacings.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</App.Resources>
```

The styles resolve at runtime but I can't seem to get intellisense for them during design time (even though the designer shows the proper colors) Notice the  squigglies: [image]

I also tried adding a code behind for my styles in the resource project and consume like this:

```
<App.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Styles:Brushes/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But had the same result.

Has anyone successfully been able to enable XAML intellisense for Resource Dictionaries packaged in Nugets in VS2017?

Comment: Have you try to open XAML file as file with content type xaml simply in solution explorer? (Right click the xaml file and select Open With... In popup select "XAML Designer with Encoding" and click OK.)

Comment: Hi @Leo-MSFT! Unfortunately opening it with encoding doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Good news and bad news. When I disable resharper the error squigglies go away but I still don't get auto complete intellisense working.

Comment: What's the result if you reference to the dll project directly instead of nuget? And for the auto complete intellisense, can you check if the value for registry: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\Text Editor\XAML\Auto List Members" is "1”?

Answer (score 1):

Our resource IntelliSense is currently based on the designer, so if the designer is able to resolve the resource correctly then the IntelliSense should be able to display it as well. Let's try a few things:

1. Resharper - Try to disable it completely or even uninstall it (at least temporarily).
2. Completions - What happens when you press Ctrl+j when the caret is in your resource in the editor? Do you get the completion list then?
3. Does the designer update when you change your resource to a different one?

If none of this works would it be possible for you to share a repro project with us? You can either post a link to a share here or use the Send Feedback tool in VS to create a feedback ticket (mention my name so I can find it easily).

Comment: Marco - appreciate your response!
1) Done resharper is gone and the problem still persists
2) CTRL+J brings up the completions list but the list does not show the resources contained in my nuget package
3) Yes, the designer always seems to function as expected (applies the style contained in my nuget)

I've put a repro project up here: https://github.com/jhorst11/xamlrepro